# Data from table not showing

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I am working on a SSRS report that's been developed by someone before me. The query pulls everything that I need it to except for the data off a table called "legheader". I have played around with joining the legheader a different way (inner join) and joining it to a different table. No matter what I try, I am either left with the same issue or no data completely.

Here is some sample data. You can see "trip number" and "driver" is not being populated:
[image]

Here is the query for the dataset:

[image]

Here are some relationships for the tables:

[image]

Comment: If you inner join to a table that is outerjoined, it effectively makes the outer join an inner join. ord is outerjoined but your stp is innerjoined to ord. 
can you confim that the data does match manually? I.E.  return the lgh_number in your query from the STP table, and look up that value in the lgh table

Comment: @Harry - not to mention that ord is in the WHERE which also effectively makes it a INNER JOIN (`AND ord.status - 'AVH'`). It looks like it should work if the data is all there.

Comment: Hey Harry, thanks for the input. I will look to see what I can do with these joins to hopefully pull the data.

Comment: From your original post, I am not sure I understand? I think this answers your question? 
I can pull data by doing a:

Comment: select top 1 * from legheader l
inner join stops s
on l.lgh_number = s.lgh_number